# Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'ProductDetailCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am basically creating an angular single page application. I am getting error Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'ProductDetailCtrl' is not a function, got undefined.

productDetailCtrl.js code

```
(function() {

    angular
        .module("productManagement")
        .controller("productDetailCtrl", ["productResource", productDetailCtrl]);

    function productDetailCtrl(productResource)
    {

        var vm = this;

        productResource.query(function(data) {
            vm.product = data;

            vm.title = "Product Detail:" + vm.product.name;

            if (vm.product.tags) {
                vm.product.tagList = vm.product.tags.toString();
            }

        });
    }
}());
```

productResource.js file

```
(function () {

    angular
        .module("common.services")
        .factory("productResource",
        ["$resource", productResource]);

    function productResource($resource) {
        return $resource("/api/products/:id",
            {

                query: {
                    method: 'GET',
                    isArray: true
                }
            });
    }
}());
```

Could somebody tell me what the problem is ?

Comment: try the format suggested in the Angular docs (under controllers): https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di in your produceDetailsCtrl file. also did you make sure to include the files in the html?

Comment: You've defined your productDetailsCtrl with a lower case 'p', but you're using it with an upper case 'P'

Comment: Thanks Eric. Well spotted.